# Measure of a Union of different translates of a set

Tags: measure-theory

I'm self-studying for prelims and a certain question came up that I have been unable to answer:

Given a sequence $\{a_n\}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and $F$ a positive (Lebesgue) measure set, show that the set

$$\cup_N F + a_n $$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$ up to a set of measure zero.

So it's clearly true if $F$ is an open interval, but I'm not quite sure how to extend. Any hints/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me just note that [Question 410434](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410434/sum-of-a-countable-dense-set-and-a-set-of-positive-measure/410527#410527), of which this question is supposedly a "duplicate", actually came after this question.  In principle, we should have closed 410434 as a duplicate of this question.  However, apparently it's not possible to close a question as a duplicate of another question that doesn't have an answer.