# Shifting a set of positive measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $m(A)>0,$ m the lebesgue measure. I want to show that $m(\mathbb{R} \setminus (A + \mathbb{Q}))=0.$

Comment: If you want to show, please go ahead... If you have problem after trying for some time, please post your approach...

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410434/sum-of-a-countable-dense-set-and-a-set-of-positive-measure?rq=1).